# Cordova iOS localStorage old values

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Each time appp is opened, user recieves data in Ajax request, it is stored in browser localStorage, and when user next time opens app, it shows localStorage values from the very first time they were set. Seems like after initially setting localStorage items, they won't change. They work fine during app, but when opening it again, there still are the very first values.

App is built on iOS and Android using Cordova latest version (as of current), using jQuery Ajax requests and browser localStorage.

Example:

1. User opens app for first time.
2. Access token is requested and is saved in localStorage `localStorage.setItem('token', '1234');`
3. User uses app for some time and exits.
4. Next time user is opening app and gets token, it is again saved in localStorage `localStorage.setItem('token', 'abcd');`
5. User uses app, then quits.
6. Again opening app and checking localStorage, the stored access token is `1234` from the first time.

Answer (score 0):

iOS considers any data stored inside the Webview of an app (HTML5 Local Storage, WebSQL, IndexedDB, Cookies, etc.) be temporary/cache data.

Therefore, if an iOS device starts to run low on space, iOS may decide to wipe the Webview data to recover space.
When this happens, the app name on the Home screen changes to "Cleaning..." and when you next launch your app, all your Webview data is gone.

For this reason, I moved from storing data inside the Webview of Cordova apps to storing it in a native SQLite database using the [cordova-sqlite-storage plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage).
The native DB file is considered "proper" data by iOS so is not wiped when an iOS device runs low on storage space.

I empirically tested both scenarios by filling an iPad with movies until it was running low on space, triggering iOS to start its "cleaning" of installed apps.

For more info, see [this related issue](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/361).

Comment: I've read about this issue, but this is not the case this time. Because localStorage data aren't cleaned, they still exist, it just uses older values, and it feels like they aren't updated. Well, they are updated during app, but when relaunching, there are still old values.