# LocalStorage is removed when cordova app restarted

Tags: ios, cordova, indexeddb, angular-local-storage

I'm developing a Cordova app, when I restart the app in ios all localStorage and indexedDB are deleted.
This phenomenon occurs intermittently, and once the issue is reproduced, it occurs continuously. I did a lot of searching on Google, but I couldn't figure out the exact cause.
Please tell me what could be the cause of this phenomenon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156915/777265

Comment: Thank you for your link, but my device have enough storage.

Comment: Still, if you switch to a native SQLite DB then your problem will go away. Any data stored in the Webview is considered temporary by the OS and liable to be wiped.

Comment: You're right. But in my code localStorage is used in many places. So if i use db sqlite i have to change these code to async function. T.T

Comment: The quota for localStorage on iOS is way smaller than Android.

So even if your device has lots of storage you can only save around ~5MB.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921048/limit-of-localstorage-on-iphone

You should be able to save larger amounts of data in indexeddb bus as you say that is async as well.